# outdated ACL on folders with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I use Powershell to pull in data about user accounts, some of which includes details about an user's home folder.

I have been using get-item on folders to get the ACL to make sure an user has proper access to their home folder.
An example of my code is:

```
((get-item C:\exampleFolder).GetAccessControl('access')).Access
```

This provided me the list I needed and works great. However, if an user's username changes, it can take some time (like 5- 10 minutes) before Powershell can see the change even though viewing the folder's properties reflects the changes nearly instantaneously.

I am just seeing if there is a better way to pull the ACL data so that what I see in folder property page is what Powershell gets.

first world issue for me really, just trying to make my code a little bit more efficient.

Edit: This is a change in a username on a domain though Active Directory, not a username on a local machine.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `Get-ACL`

Comment: This could be a delay with replication between DC's (Domain Controller's); are you accessing Active Directory and running your PowerShell scripts under the same account on the same machine? In your powershell console can you check which DC you're connected to (gpresult) and then in AD connect to that specific DC and change a user's name to see if there's still a delay?

Comment: same user, same machine.
i will give your suggestion a shot next time i get the chance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Get-ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-6) Cmdlet. This will output an object with an Access property listing all users with Access and their Access Level.

If you want to, you could use this to make a function to get more explicit data like this:

```
  function Get-Permissions ($folder) {
  (get-acl $folder).access | select `
        @{Label="Identity";Expression={$_.IdentityReference}}, `
        @{Label="Right";Expression={$_.FileSystemRights}}, `
        @{Label="Access";Expression={$_.AccessControlType}}, `
        @{Label="Inherited";Expression={$_.IsInherited}}, `
        @{Label="Inheritance Flags";Expression={$_.InheritanceFlags}}, `
        @{Label="Propagation Flags";Expression={$_.PropagationFlags}}
        }
```

This you could easily pipe on to a `| Format-Table -Auto` or however you wish to visually consume your output.

Comment: this looks like an excellent answer, though it seems my code and yours are giving me the exact same data, just with slightly different names due to the label parts of your code.
i will have to experiment next time i get a request for a name change, just in case that get-ACL cmdlet is more effective despite.

Comment: Ah should have said that with the function that yes, the data is the same, the renaming of the labels would just be to have it match the same naming you have in the GUI :)

Comment: oh i see, that in itself is helpful, thanks.
my issue is powershell not seeing updated ACL records very quickly, i think powershell is caching and not showing me new data perhaps.
for example, my username changes from User1 to UserA, the ACL as read by powershell will read User1 for a little bit before finally saying UserA, even though right after the username change, the folder properties reflect the change.
it might be worth mentioning that this is a user account in Active Directory, not a home setup.